# check missing values across two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have two tables for items and categories. An item can be in multiple categories. Please check the following fiddle for tables.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b248/5

Now I need to find out missing values from both the tables. I mean for some items, in category table the category value is zero. For some other items, which has category value in items table, but are missing altogether from category table. For the items in category table , whose category value is zero I am using the following query.

```
SELECT item_id,itemname,category_name FROM item i JOIN category c ON i.category_id=c.category_id GROUP BY c.item_id HAVING MAX(i.category_id)=0 ORDER BY i.item_name
```

How can I change it so it will fetch the items from item table whose entry is missing from category table.I need both items, i.e items whose category value is zero and the ones which is missing from category table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
select i.*
from items as i
where
    not exists
    (
         select * 
         from categories as c
         where c.item_id = i.item_id and c.cat_id <> 0
    )
```

Comment: It is fine in terms of performance if I select from a table with around 25000 results ?

Comment: I think it is if you have proper indexes, you could try it

Comment: Also I need to get the category name from category table. How can I retrieve it ? Now I am getting rows from items table only.

Comment: do you need all categories for each item?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i.item_id,i.name,c.cat_name FROM 
items AS i LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS c ON i.item_id=c.item_id 
GROUP BY c.item_id HAVING MAX(c.cat_id)=0 OR c.cat_name is null
ORDER BY i.name
```